# how to configure a timer job to run in specific servers?

Tags: 2010, timer-jobs

If I have a big environment with 100,000 users, I am planning to split the servers for WFE, Application Servers and Batch Processing.

I wonder if there is an specific way to enable/install specific timer jobs only in one server or group of servers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it from the TimerJob definitions by specifying the SPServer and the SPJobLockType. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms461120.aspx)

Though this would be easier if your solution was not already in production

Comment: what about if I dont know the name of the server when I am developing? probably put the name on the property bag and read it from there in the constructor? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spserver.aspx